# Docker postgres starting automation can not create database due to error

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, docker, containers

I want to create a shell script which automates the creation and running and creating database in a postgres database using docker.

I want to use the `docker postgres` official package for postgres in docker.

The script that I use is as follows:

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 shared_network;
docker kill postgres_linker;
docker rm postgres_linker;
docker run --name postgres_linker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=blahblahblah -d --net shared_network --ip 172.18.0.2 postgres:10-alpine;
docker exec -it postgres_linker psql -U postgres -c "create database linker;";
```

But when I run this I get the following output without any database being created:

```
Error response from daemon: network with name shared_network already exists
postgres_linker
postgres_linker
b2a9fd4d6e25b62d60adb05c8b6b653a1b55ec7a869c4728677d6289f5cddd63
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The first line of this log is OK, the second and third are too, The problem is that `psql` does not run the command on the postgres container althogh the command I am trying to run is correct. If I run the last command seperately from my shell script:

```
docker exec -it postgres_linker psql -U postgres -c "create database linker;";
```

It does not give me error! and it works!
Why is this behavior happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.
Unfortunately I thought that when postgres container is run the server is up and running immediately.
It was not true and it takes some time to come up. so I have needed to add some delay.
So the resulting script file should look like this:

```
docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 shared_network;
docker kill postgres_linker;
docker rm postgres_linker;
docker run --name postgres_linker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=blahblahblah -d --net shared_network --ip 172.18.0.2 postgres:10-alpine;
sleep 5;
docker exec -it postgres_linker psql -U postgres -c "create database linker;";
```